# Phonegap iOS app runs slow

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I created a Phonegap app with HTML + CSS using jQuery Mobile. Everything works fine except for the following glitches:

1. `<a href="url"> Click here </a>` - link with anchor tag is extremely slow, and sometimes doesn't open up the browser to load the page.
2. Javascript used to draw Google maps with certain predefined locations page doesn't load at all, or if it does it takes an awful amount of time.

I would appreciate any help/suggestion.